# Override asp.NET Session object

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms, overriding

Is it possible in asp.net to change the Session object so that when it is used to set/get , it does something else?

EX:

`Session["variable"]` I'll like it to do behind the covers `Session[guid + variable]` append to the key a GUID

Update:
Some of you asked way do I what to do this?
I want to do this to make the session unique for each tab in the browser. I'm forced to use the session. The guid will be a unique tab id. ([see solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2839183/901249))

Comment: Why would you want to do that? How would you know what key to retrieve?

Answer (score 4):

You could wrap Session with your own class that pre-pends a guid to the session key, and then use that class instead of Session. With that said, I'm not sure why you would want to.

**Update**

If you need the data to be unique for each browser tab, use [`ViewState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate.aspx) instead. It's used to persist state between requests for a particular page/browser window/tab.

Comment: +1 I agree. Don't see the reason to do this. It seems that OP thinks that Session and Cache are the same, hence the need for an extra unique identifier.

Comment: @jrummell yes, i know about ViewState, but the legacy code that I'm changing forces me to use Session. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @jrummell No I can not. If I could have i wouldn't have asked this question, in the first place. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok, but you should know that you're hammering a nail with a screw driver.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own session provider for ASP.NET and after this you gain full control over your session data.

Answer (score 1):

**For Webforms, you can create a base System.Web.UI.Page class that all your pages inherit from that expose your methods. Like so:**

```
public partial class _Default : BasePage {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Person p = new Person {
            FirstName = "MyFName",
            LastName = "MyLName"
        };
        SetSessionData<Person>("somevalue", p);
        var person = GetSessionData<Person>("somevalue");
    }
}

public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page {
    internal void SetSessionData<T>(string name, T value) {
        this.Session[string.Format("{0}_{1}", value.GetType().GUID, name)] = value;
    }
    internal T GetSessionData<T>(string name) {
        return (T)this.Session[string.Format("{0}_{1}", typeof(T).GUID, name)];
    }
}

public class Person {
    public Person() {
        ID = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

}
```

**For MVC: Another suggestion would be to create a "Base" Page class that all your controllers inherit from that expose your methods. Like so:**

```
public class BaseController : Controller   {
    internal void SetSessionData<T>(string name, T value) {            
        this.Session[string.Format("{0}_{1}",value.GetType().GUID,name)] = value;
    }
    internal T GetSessionData<T>(string name) {
        return (T)this.Session[string.Format("{0}_{1}", typeof(T).GUID, name)];
    }
}
```

Then, you can get or set items as so:

```
        Person p = new Person{
            FirstName = "MyFName",
            LastName  = "MyLName"
        };
        SetSessionData<Person>("somevalue", p);
        var person = GetSessionData<Person>("somevalue");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this requires a lot of code change and testing, and i cannot afford it.

Comment: Updated code example to include non MVC application - which is basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in the direct sense, without creating your own session provider.  A possible work around could be to create two new methods.  Possibly put them in the Global.asax

```
public String GetSession(String variable)
{
    return Session[guid+variable];
}

public void SetSession
{
        Session.Add(guid+variable, value);
}
```