# Duplicate Tab copying sessionStorage in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, sessionstorage

When a tab is duplicated in Chrome, is `sessionStorage` also duplicated?

I noticed that in IE it is not.

Answer (score 15):

In Chrome, Yes. And you've hit on an important distinction. The contents of `sessionStorage` is "copied" not "shared". Any changes made to `sessionStorage` after the tab is duplicated are not reflected in the other tab's `sessionStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you duplicate the tab, the sessionStorage data is also duplicated on the copied tab.