# Detect URL if it is already opened and throw pop-up : HTML+JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a simple **HTML page with JavaScript** and i want to run my application in such a way that if it is already opened in another tab then a pop-up should come mentioning 'Page is already opened'

Kindly provide a solution on this as that would be really helpful.....

Comment: Did you search? Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690666/check-if-my-website-is-open-in-another-tab

Comment: that is not working for me....

Comment: can u pls suggest an answer or place the code in here... if you please.....