# VueJS perform background operations only on one tab

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js, local-storage, query-optimization

I wanna improve my VueJS application system.

Currently, each browser tab once per 20 seconds makes synchronization with the server - getting notifications and the latest settings.

It's problematic because a typical user often has 20+ opened tabs, so each synchronizes itself.

I know, that I can share the Vuex Store between tabs, using localStorage, and currently I'm doing this, so I don't have to synchronize everyone tab, cause if one of them synchronizes, all of them will have current data about app notifications and settings.

So the question is - **how to do it?**

I tried using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690666/check-if-my-website-is-open-in-another-tab/43291970#43291970), but what if the user closes the tab? How to control that, one of the tabs synchronized the data?

Thanks in advance, have a nice day!

Comment: here have some solution please check it up https://github.com/gabrielmbmb/vuex-multi-tab-state

Comment: @Comsphere, yes, I know and currently using it, thanks. Synchronizing Store between tabs is easy to do, but I don know how to limit tabs, which can synchronize with the server to only one.

Comment: Is it better to check on how many tab is being open by using the javascript here?

function logTabsForWindows(windowInfoArray) {
  for (windowInfo of windowInfoArray) {
    console.log(`Window: ${windowInfo.id}`);
    console.log(windowInfo.tabs.map((tab) => {return tab.url}));
  }
}

var gettingAll = browser.windows.getAll({populate: true})
gettingAll.then(logTabsForWindows);

Comment: Hmmm, what about `ReferenceError: browser is not defined` error?

Comment: sorry for late reply here have some tips for you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/getAll

Comment: Yeah, I found it, but still I'm getting the same error. Then I've tried `let browser = window.browser || window.chrome`, and now I'm getting: `Cannot read property 'getAll' of undefined`.

Comment: Isn't it a feature only for the browser extensions?

Comment: it can't customize for whole browser such as edge, firefox, chrome, here is some chrome example to use it https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#type-Tab

Comment: here is some demo for you, https://codepen.io/AndrewTechLead/pen/VwKPGoW, suggest to put this link in new browser, with this new browser open several tab to try.