# Prevent Opening a new Tab in Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am working on a project and I want to incorporate a feature where a user should not able to open a new tab just like in many exams we give online we can't open a new tab same feature I want to implement using Spring boot and Angular. I am new in this please help me out.

Comment: The user should not be able to open your Angular website in another tab or open any site at all in another tab?

Comment: Also, what have you tried and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I have tried to search a lot but I dont have much idea how to implement please can you give some direction I have checked to disable right click but it wont help I need to prevent opening a new tab in same browser as well as I want prevent it to open the same link in any browser

Comment: you want to prevent the ctrl+click or mouse wheel click? (Both actions opens a new tab in windows)

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I don't think there is any - non hacky / if any - way to achieve this and also I currently can not think of any reason why to do that in a web application.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can leverage **localStorage** to check if there're other tabs already opened.
   check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690666/check-if-my-website-is-open-in-another-tab)
2. Use the **Service Worker** to get a list of clients (tabs) that are currently opened (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients).

https://web.whatsapp.com/ is an example of what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much I will try to implement this. It looks suitable