# Reload current page if user submits form with Ctrl-click or Shift-click

Tags: javascript, woocommerce, tabs, submit, reload

In WooCommerce in product page, sometimes users click on Add-to-cart button while pressing Ctrl or Shift keys, for opening the resulting page in a new tab/window.

In this cases, **I need current page to reload**. How can I do it?

Consider that Add-to-cart button submits the form.

Comment: I guess you will either have to implement a rather complex solution a la [Check if my website is open in another tab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23690666/1427878), or add additional event handlers to the button to check if ctrl/shift were pressed when it was clicked.

Comment: Check this ? - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ctrlkey.asp Just add on click and if they hold ctrl to reload i guess ? Or use addEventListener to listen for submit event ?

Answer (score 0):

At first stop normal submitting with `event.preventDefault()` on submit event form then doing any thing you want with the click event on the add to cart button.

You can do it with something like this:

```js
function handleOnsubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
}

function handleOnclick(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey || event.shiftKey) {
    location.reload();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
  }

}
```

```html
<form action="https://stackoverflow.com/" id="myForm" onsubmit="handleOnsubmit(event)">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <button type="submit" onclick="handleOnclick(event)">Add to cart</button>
</form>
```

In Woocommerce probably you should use `addEventListener` for the form and the add to cart button in the single product page. like this:

```
document.querySelector("form.cart").addEventListener("submit", handleOnsubmit);
document.querySelector("form.cart button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", handleOnclick);

function handleOnsubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
}

function handleOnclick(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey || event.shiftKey) {
    location.reload();
  } else {
    document.querySelector("form.cart").submit();
  }

}
```