# Any way for a tab to "wake" another tab (from the same site) out of 'suspension'?

Tags: javascript, html

#### Question

This will obviously vary by browser and device and probably other factors too (e.g. battery level), but if a tab hasn't been used in a few minutes, then I've noticed that Chrome Desktop seems to wake tabs once per minute to run timers. I'm wondering if there's a way to trigger a specific tab to wake up for a moment?

To give you an example, I thought that perhaps if a page is listening to a specific `BroadcastChannel` channel, then maybe it wakes up for a moment if there is an incoming message. Just a wild guess. But on Chrome Desktop that doesn't appear to be the case.

Are there any approaches that might work here? Even if they're hacky, and only work in certain browsers, etc. I need the page to 'wake' within 10 seconds of my "prodding" it from another tab.

#### Additional Context

The reason for this is because I need to trigger a notification from a specific tab if the user already has it open, such that if they click the notification, that existing tab is focused. Otherwise I just trigger the notification from the current/active tab and a new tab is opened when they click the notification. I.e. I don't want to open a new tab if they already have a copy of that page open.

What I really need here is a way to have a notification's `onclick` focus an existing tab of the same site. And `window.open("", "foo").focus()` only works if *this* window was the one that created the "foo" tab. So my workaround is to try to somehow 'wake up' the relevant tab and have it trigger the notification itself, such that the `onclick` can simply call `window.focus()`.

**TL;DR**: I need to send a message to a particular same-origin tab if it exists (based on the URL) such that it can trigger a notification that will focus itself. I need the message to be received within ~10 seconds.