# Detect multiple chrome tabs opened of the same app in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

Is there a way to detect if multiple browser tabs are opened of the same application.

**Let's say i have www.test.com and i open 4 tabs of this website.**

Is there a way to detect that multiple tabs are opened in JavaScript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop people having my website loaded on multiple tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008177/stop-people-having-my-website-loaded-on-multiple-tabs)

Answer (score 4):

You can use my [sysend.js library](https://github.com/jcubic/sysend.js), it use localStorage to send messages between open tabs/windows. All to do is this code:

```
sysend.on('notification', function() {
   sysend.broadcast('multiple');
});
sysend.on('multiple', function() {
   // this will fire n-1 times if there are n tabs open if n > 1
   alert('multiple pages');
});
sysend.broadcast('notification');
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/9sgkxg6f/4/)

Answer (score 2):

There is, but it's not guaranteed to always be correct:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var applicationCount = localStorage.getItem("applicationCount");
  if (!applicationCount) {
    applicationCount = 0;
  }
  localStorage.setItem("applicationCount", ++applicationCount);
}

window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  var applicationCount = localStorage.getItem("applicationCount");
  if (!applicationCount) {
    applicationCount = 1;
  }
  localStorage.setItem("applicationCount", --applicationCount);
};
```

It uses the localStorage which is shared among the tabs. But note that if the browser crashes, the value is still saved.

Comment: I know, thanks, i'm trying to make check for user inactivity  on the page. I made logic for that, only problem is if user opens multiple tabs if he's not active in the first opened he will we loged out from all  others tabs... And i don't want that.