# Angular 9 - Does opening a routerLink in another tab create a second application instance?

Tags: angular, tabs, state, single-page-application

Assume that I have an `<a routerLink="/foo">` tag, where `/foo` is routed to `FooPageComponent`, which renders content into the `<router-outlet />` of `AppComponent`. If I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Click</kbd> on this link, `/foo` will be opened in a **second tab**. Does this mean that it will be an **independent, second instance of my single-page application**?

I know the second page uses the same server, localStorage etc., so it's not completely independent. But will it have its own instances of global objects (like the router, singleton services etc.)? Will it also run the `APP_INITIALIZER` code?

In general, is it good practice in case of single-page applications to let users open pages in new tabs, or is it better to stay in the same tab, and use for example popups instead of new tabs?

Comment: No, they don't share their Services, they create their own instances of services.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829228/way-around-asp-net-session-being-shared-across-multiple-tab-windows/2839183#2839183) may be helpful if you want to prevent users from using your application on multiple tabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is yes, it will create a whole new instance of your app, and rerun the `APP_INITIALIZER`.

And about your second question, there is no practise that is better, it depends on what you want to achieve.